# How to apply data dynamically on initialisation for chart.js in angular?

Tags: angular, chart.js

I have a series of bodyweights, say 80, 83, 79, 85, that I have retrieved from my server. I would like to apply this set of data to the chart on initialisation.

Below is my ts file:

```
export class DailyTrackingComponent implements OnInit {

  bodyweightData: number[] = [];   timelineLabel: string[] = [];
     constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

      ** for-loop function that retrieves the data and pushes each individual bodyweight number to this.bodyweightData and pushes a string to this.timelineLabel for every bodyweight number pushed ***

    parseOptions(Chart, chartOptions());

    const chart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('bodyweightChart') as HTMLCanvasElement,
      {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: this.timelineLabel,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Bodyweight',
              data: this.bodyweightData,
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                gridLines: {
                  color: '#e9ecef',
                  zeroLineColor: '#e9ecef',
                },
                ticks: {
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      }
    );   }
```

The problem is the chart does not show anything, but if I statically put in an arbitrary number array into data under `data.datasets` it shows up as expected.

Comment: Do you use an http call? If so you have to wait for the result to arrive

Comment: @FedericoAndreoli yes I did, how do I do that? The function is in the form `this.httpService.getBodyweight().subscribe(response => {this.bodyweightData.push(response)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is correct, just put the graph initialization inside `.subscribe(...)`.

Otherwise you can put it in another function and call it inside the `subscribe()` method.

```
this.httpService.getBodyweight().subscribe(response => 
  {
      this.bodyweightData.push(response)ù
      //Build graph here or call a function that builds it
  })
```

This is because the code after the server call is run before the response actually arrives, so the variable you are using to build the graph is still empty

Comment: Thank you so much! You've saved me after 4 hours of pain ahaha

Comment: If I would like to update data, how can I do that? I have tried to add a method after ngOnInit to do something like `onClick(): void {this.bodyweightData=[100,110];}` but it doesn't seem to be working? I was wondering if I need to add any other functions

Comment: There sould be an "updateChart function". See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Otherwise you can re-initialize the graph , but i think it's a bit clunky